# Win32 Executable Output Parsing with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

my $PSVersionTable output is as follows:

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      7.0.1
PSEdition                      Core
GitCommitId                    7.0.1
OS                             Microsoft Windows 10.0.19041
Platform                       Win32NT
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0…}
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
WSManStackVersion              3.0
```

If I enter

```
wsl -l | Get-Member
```

the output informs me that the output type is a String.

If I enter

```
(wsl -l).GetType()
```

the output informs me that the output type is Array.

The entire reason I'm looking at this is that I was trying to parse the output of that command and for a long, frustrating time, I was thinking that I was working with a single, contiguous string with embedded carriage return / line feeds, but it appears I'm actually working with an array of strings.

So my question: what do the parentheses around the command do to seemingly change the nature of the output of the executable? Is it that without the parentheses the output from 'wsl -l' is being streamed to Get-Member one line (array element) at a time?

Thank you!

Comment: It's a string array with or without the parentheses. `$var = wsl -l`  `$var.gettype()`  `$var.GetType().basetype.name
Array`

Comment: The pipeline `|` _enumerates_ the contents of the array, and `Get-Member` only shows output once per distinct input type - both expressions resolve to an array containing strings :)

Comment: If `wsl -l` outputs a single line, you will have a string. Otherwise it's an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Member) to inspect an object as-is, you mustn't use the pipeline, because the pipeline *enumerates* objects that are collection-like, and `Get-Member` then reports the (distinct set of) types among the *elements* of the collection.

Instead, **use `Get-Member -InputObject`, which reports on collections *as a whole***:

```sh
Get-Member -InputObject (wsl -l) # -> shows the members of type System.Object[]
```

---

**PowerShell *streams* the stdout output from external programs such as `wsl`, *line by line***. That is, it sends each line as it is being received to the pipeline.

If you assign the command's output to a *variable* or *enclose the command in `()`, the [grouping operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#grouping-operator--)*, the **stream output is *collected***:

- If there's only ***one* output line**, a (single) **`[string]` instance** is returned.
- If there are ***multiple* output lines**, PowerShell collects them in a regular, **`[object[]]`-typed *array*** for you, whose elements are `[string]` instances in this case.

If you want to avoid this ambiguity and **ensure that the result is *always* an array**, you can use **`@()`**, the [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) - `@(wsl -l)` - or, on assigning to a variable, *type-constrain* that variable as an array - `[array] $out = wsl -l`

**To get a single, potentially multi-line string representation of the output**, use the **[`-join` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Join)**:

```sh
(wsl -l) -join "`n"   # or use [Environment]::NewLine instead of "`n"
```

<sup>`[Environment]::NewLine` returns the platform-appropriate newline char. / sequence (LF-only (`` "`n" ``) on Unix, CRLF (`` "`r`n" ``) on Windows). However, PowerShell happily accepts either form on all platforms.</sup>

Note:

- While the [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Out-String) cmdlet would return a single, multi-line string too, it *invariably adds a trailing newline*. (If you were to use `-NoNewLine`, it wouldn't use *any* newlines).

---

If you're using **PowerShell [Core] v6.2+**, you can alternatively use the **[`Join-String` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Join-String)**:

```sh
wsl -l | Join-String -Separator "`n"
```